# How to highlight selected items in the Adapter in Android(Java)

Tags: java, android

couldn't highlight the selected item in the adapter recyclerview.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
    ChannelMainBean bean = mList.get(position);
    holder.tvContent.setText(bean.getChannelName());
    if (holder.selectedItem == position){
        holder.tvContent.setBackground(ResUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_network_border_blue));
    }
    else{
        holder.tvContent.setBackground(ResUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_network_background_default));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This**

```
private int selectedItem = -1;

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        ChannelMainBean bean = mList.get(position);
        holder.tvContent.setText(bean.getChannelName());
        
        holder.tvContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedItem = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if (selectedItem == position){
            holder.tvContent.setBackground(ResUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_network_border_blue));
        }
        else{
            holder.tvContent.setBackground(ResUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_network_background_default));
        }
    }
    }
```

`selectedItem` is integer variable set global and than set click listener on `TextView` and inside click method set click position in to `selectedItem` and than `notifyDataSetChanged()` for update background for text view